# Swipe views with tabs get and change current fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How can I get the current fragment from a tab with swipe view and modify it's layout from my MainActivity? It's that possibile?

Below the application UI, I need to modify the background of each fragment and add on top a new ImageView at run time when a new entry is inserted.

[image]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private ViewPager mViewPager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Set up the action bar.
            final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
            // primary sections of the activity.
            SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
            // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
            // a reference to the Tab.
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

            // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
                // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
                // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
                // this tab is selected.
                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                                .setTabListener(this));
            }
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.action_menu_settings:
                    openSettings();
                    break;
                default:
                    openSettings();
                    break;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
            // the ViewPager.
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }

        public void openSettings() {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public static String FIRST_SECTION_TITLE = "Today";
public static String SECOND_SECTION_TITLE = "Week";
public static String THIRD_SECTION_TITLE = "Month";

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    Fragment fragment;

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = WeekFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = MonthFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        default:
            fragment = TodayFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return FIRST_SECTION_TITLE;
        case 1:
            return SECOND_SECTION_TITLE;
        case 2:
            return THIRD_SECTION_TITLE;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Fragment (all 3 fragments are equal, just the xml layout changes)

```
public class MonthFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static MonthFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
    MonthFragment fragment = new MonthFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_month, container, false);;
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current position from mViewPager.getCurrentItem().
Also, try using FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter.

EDIT: Looks like you return a new instance each time.
In this case, you can try this

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(mViewPager.getId())
```

Comment: Do you mean fragmentManager.findFragmentById(mViewPager.getId()) ? Because I can't find any getFragmentById() method from the fragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by moving all the application logic in each Fragment (since a Fragment is a kind of Activity). The problem is that with the below implementation the Fragment is created at each tab swipe change, which means that it does not save the previous state.